# Android custom input validation for numbers

Tags: c#, android, validation, input, xamarin

So I'm working in Xamarin to make a C# android app for school and at some point the user needs to type in an IBAN number.
I want to check if the input equals 4 times 4 numbers with a dash between them (e.g. 1234-1234-1234-1234), 
sadly I have no idea how to do this and I haven't found anything that could help me, so far.

This is my activity where I need to check if the input of "mTxtIBAN" equals the IBAN number.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace LoginSystem
{
[Activity (Label = "SubDetailsBankActivity")]           
public class SubDetailsBankActivity : Activity
{
    private Button mBtnContinue;
    private EditText mTxtIBAN;
    private EditText mTxtBIC;

    private TextView mIBANWarning;
    private TextView mBICWarning;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.SubBankDetails);
        // Create your application here
        string email = Intent.GetStringExtra ("Email") ?? "Data not available";
        string firstName = Intent.GetStringExtra ("FirstName") ?? "Data not available";
        string lastName = Intent.GetStringExtra ("LastName") ?? "Data not available";
        string streetNumber = Intent.GetStringExtra ("StreetNumber") ?? "Data not available";
        string cityCode = Intent.GetStringExtra ("CityCode") ?? "Data not available";
        string country = Intent.GetStringExtra ("Country") ?? "Data not available";


        mBtnContinue = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnContinue);
        mTxtIBAN = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.IBAN);
        mTxtBIC = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.BIC);

        mIBANWarning = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.IBANtext);
        mBICWarning = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.BICtext);

        mBtnContinue.Click += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (mTxtIBAN.Text.Length != 0 && mTxtBIC.Text.Length != 0) {
                var newSub = new Intent(this, typeof(SubDetailsComplete));
                newSub.PutExtra ("Email", email);
                newSub.PutExtra ("FirstName", firstName);
                newSub.PutExtra ("LastName", lastName);
                newSub.PutExtra ("StreetNumber", streetNumber);
                newSub.PutExtra ("CityCode",cityCode);
                newSub.PutExtra ("Country", country);
                newSub.PutExtra ("IBAN", mTxtIBAN.Text);
                newSub.PutExtra ("BIC", mTxtBIC.Text);

                StartActivity (newSub);
            }
            if (mTxtIBAN.Text.Length == 0){
                mIBANWarning.Text = "Fill in your IBAN number!";
            }
            if (mTxtBIC.Text.Length == 0){
                mBICWarning.Text = "Fill in your BIC number!";
            }
        };
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: Hope you might know about it...Try to use Regular expression to match your string....

Comment: @Srinivasan I do not know about that, but I'll look it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it this way:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\d{4}?-\d{4}?-\d{4}?-\d{4}?$");
if (rgx.IsMatch(mTxtIBAN.Text))
{
    // valid IBAN
}
```